# I need help understanding the dynamics of this oscillator

Tags: bjt, oscillator, induction

I'm a beginner at circuits (I'm a high school student interested in electronics), and I'm currently working on a school project about a **Magnetostriction Oscillator**. The circuit construction is as follows, and I need some help understanding certain aspects of the same.

[image]

So from my understanding, the circuit working is as follows:

- When the battery is attached a voltage V is supplied to the LC oscillator. Which induces an oscillating flux in the rod: A question I had is that since its a DC supply, won't the capacitor saturate after the time constant is completed, making the induced magnetic field constant (all current directed through L1)
- The apparently oscillating magnetic field in the rod induces an EMF in L2 - which gets amplified through the BJT and gets fed back into the parallel LC oscillator (is this why it acts as an AC voltage allowing the parallel LC to oscillate??): I get the induced EMF (provided magnetic field is oscillating) - but don't get the amplification. Won't the induced emf/current get amplified and move towards the reference ground node instead of the LC oscillator?? If it does could you please explain why?
- Any additional help on understanding how the LC circuit oscillates and how the transistor plays a role in the same would be much appreciated!

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: This is an addition to your earlier question on the same subject.  You should edit the existing question to add in this additional material.

Comment: Also research [magnetostriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostriction) for details on what this specifically means.

Answer (score 2):

The transistor is a voltage-controlled current source, moderated by the voltage typically around Vbe=0.6 for Ic=1mA and it is exponential.  The smaller turns of coil to the base is like a step-down transformer which also lowers the impedance to the base or conversely raises the low base-emitter incremental resistance when conducting that the load sees on the secondary.

The condition required for all oscillators of any type is called the [Barkhausen (stability) Criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barkhausen_stability_criterion#:%7E:text=In%20electronics%2C%20the%20Barkhausen%20stability,Barkhausen%20(1881%E2%80%931956).). This states the gain must => 1 at the frequency where phase-shift is 0 or 360 deg. etc.  The LC at resonance is exactly 180' due to the difference between L 90 deg voltage lead and C 90 deg. current lead that adds to the fact that all base to collector currents are in opposing directions in the loop or 180 deg. Thus this satisfies the 360 deg. condition.

There is a simple way, given L and C to compute the approximate resonant frequency and impedance of each part as a function of f. The impedances have opposite reactive polarity (lead/lag) and both cancel at resonance.  The ratio of a parallel leakage R or a load R connected to the output .. back to the  base also affects this gain or Q factor but likely with the transistor gain and Q gain, it will oscillate if the feedback polarity is correct.  Search (me here for) "RLC impedance nomograph"  (for examples)

Comment: Just one small comment for clarification: The Barkhausen criterion for oscillation (it is NOT a stability criterion) requires that the LOOP GAIN is (at least) unity at the desired oscillation frequency. That is the gain of the complete feedback loop when it is opened at a suitable point for injecting a test signal.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't seem to grasp a lot of stuff you've said such as - so I would just like to clarify. when you say voltage-controlled current source - you mean essentially that the transistor offers a current gain right? So this would imply transistor behavior as an amplifier and not a switch?

Also I was just wondering how would the capacitor discharge since its connected to the DC source (if the c saturates, wouldn't the Inductance at L1 be constant and hence induction at L2 would stop??)

Comment: @LvW unity gain is called the stability criterion with H.G. Barkhausen’s posthumous name attached to it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barkhausen_stability_criterion. >1 guarantees it is a stable oscillator which otherwise is called an unstable condition for DC loops.

Comment: @ScreamingPigeon a transistor collector is a high impedance current source regulated precisely by Vbe in the linear region of Vce>=2V at max current and full hFE . But as Vce drops , so too does hFE and when collector base becomes forward biased, Vce changes exponentially from a high impedance current source to a low impedance Rce switch. When there is excess gain in the loop, the current tends to drive the Vbe in pulses the negative feedback turns it off as it “coasts”  or resonates with high impedance.

Comment: So it becomes sometimes distorted rather than a sinewave with low THD. The magnetics has hysteresis which further makes the feedback nonlinear.  we know a Schmitt trigger has hysteresis and these logic inverters also make excellent oscillators due to the RC delay time and the 2 different switching thresholds,  thus the magnetic properties , not being linear or constant V=LdI/dt depends on the stored magnetics or Remanence in certain cores.   FWIW Just FYI

Comment: Yet in this case the topic suggests a mechanical oscillator using the stored magnetic energy and mechanical motion similar to the piezo-electric motion in ceramic insulators but different.  Like a  swing oscillating with a mass  in gravity , but here an experiment to cause the magnetic particles to move enough to vibrate the material with current  in an oscillator, so you can hear the sound waves. Normally one wants to eliminate this characteristic which some have heard on SMPS magnetics.  I once had a 5V buck driving a 12V low power boost and the boost was making more noise than a water tap!

Comment: That was due to a complex behaviour called “chaos” which resulted in random noise (brown noise not pink or white) in the tiny SMT ferrite choke, Fixing that only needed a low ESR bulk cap between the two SMPS to swamp the current noise from the magnetostriction  noise with PWM on the buck and PFM ( variable f) on the boost causing this freak of nature. That was 20 yrs ago when I designed a VGA head-mounted display in front of the eye to look like a 14” monitor at arm’s length.  Way before the Google Glasses using a Kopin AMLCD chip.

Comment: Tony Stewart, I know this wiki page. It is not quite correct. H. Barkhausen has formulated a criterion (his book in on my desk) which is just a necessary one.  So - it does not "guarantee" oscillation if the loop gain is unity. The other way round: If a ciruit oscillates it must have a unity loop gain.  So it is not identical with Nyquists stability criteron.

Comment: @LcV I think that is “splitting hairs” as achieving precise unity gain in a linear system is like achieving exactly 0 Ohms or components with precisely 0% tolerance error .It takes whatever  stimulus and oscillates exactly at that level. So True you can say it does not guarantee oscillation unless a stimulus exists. It will never grow to a stable level without Av>1.00000....  I believe that is what he said about Das Problem der Schwingungserzengung

Comment: The way to self-excite with unity gain is with bipolar voltages and 0 charge on caps that must charge up and in doing so excite the sinusoidal oscillation to the same level as the DC voltage ( if linear and exactly unity gain)

Comment: Tony Stewart, you misunderstood my comment. I did not speak about unity loop gain and the question how exact this can be achieved.  I also did not mention the stimulus for starting oscillations. My only point was the difference between (a) Barkhausens oscillation condition (which was the result of an observation) and (b) the stability criterion which is connected with the name Nyquist.  Both are not identical.

Comment: @LvW then I don’t understand why you contradict, because it is a stability criterion that is easily observed , proveable and stimulated only by an initial condition or noise at exactly unity gain. Is it just semantics? Because it is based on Barkhausen’s observations.

Comment: No - it is not just semantics, I think. And I did not "contradict". My only intention was to improve a wording which was not correct. Barkhausen has formulated an oscillation condition - not a "stability criterion". Example: A circuit with feedback can be unstable - although it does not oscillate. Barkhausens finding was - more or less - a result of observation and logical thinking. Instead, Nyquists criterion was based on a theoretical fundament (Cauchys "Residuen theorem") and the zero/pole location in the s-plane. So it was not "based on Barkhausen`s observation".

Comment: OK on original "Das Problem der Schwingungserzengung "  in any case exact unity gain only exists in theory and not in practice so  it's an academic issue like the perfectly linear "Wien Sien" Oscillator.